# Three.JS Pixel Manipulation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a web application which would efficiently modify the pixels of an image (feed from a webcam specifically, but I'd like to start with a basic image). I believe this can be done with Three.JS using a custom shader, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it. Does anyone know how to make it such that I might have something similar to a 2D array of pixels I could modify algorithmically?

Thanks

Comment: vanilla canvas allow you to read/write the 2D pixels array

Answer (score 0):

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/
maybe check video webcam examples here
or here: http://www.adrienbaptiste.com/webcam/
Just search for three.js + webrtc, there are a few examples